# Is it correct to use useAsyncData inside a computed property in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm making a composable which returns data about user.
I want to get user status (authenticated or guest) within request to a remote server. I store an access token in a cookie and make this request in a such way:

```
// whether the user is authenticated
const isAuthenticated: ComputedRef<boolean> = computed((): boolean => {
    // validate auth token
    if ('undefined' === typeof authToken.value || null === authToken.value) {
        return false;
    }

    // get app config
    const appConfig: any = useAppConfig();

    // make the request
    const { error } = useAsyncData<ServerResponseData, ServerResponseError>(
        'user-check-auth-token', () => $fetch(`${appConfig.api.baseUrl}/user/check-auth-token`, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken.value}`
            }
        })
    );

    // token is valid if no error happened
    return !error.value;
});
```

This code works fine, but in a console I see this warning:
`[Vue warn] Computed is still dirty after getter evaluation, likely because a computed is mutating its own dependency in its getter. State mutations in computed getters should be avoided...`

Comment: No, it isn't. There should be no side effects inside computed, and composables belong to the body of component setup, unless proven otherwise

Comment: Could you please give me a tip how to improve this composable so it would satisfy this requirement?
It'll be ok if I replace the computed property with just a simple function?

Comment: Depends on how it's supposed to work. If data is supposed to be fetched on authToken changes then call refresh() that useAsyncData returns inside a watcher

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing data from the client-side cookie, you are not expecting this to work on the server side. In that case, `useAsyncData` may not make sense here.

Comment: I'm using useCookie composible for manipulating with cookies. According to [Nuxt docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie), it's SSR friendly. Or am I wrong?